# Character in Unity scene walking backwards?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am currently working on the Flooded Grounds Unity Asset, I'm implementing an Alien NPC, with a script that tells it to follow the player.

The problem that I'm encountering is that the Alien turns his back to the player and I can't figure out why. I also tried rotating it by 180° on the Y axis (both in the transform and inside of the script using transform.rotate.y - when using the transform doesn't make any difference while using it in the update function just makes it constantly snap back and forth).

Here's a video of the issue:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tC9zJWKXXDuNZNZJbl2htBUgTPSTB4IG/view?usp=sharing

And here's the script that I'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyFollow : MonoBehaviour
 
{
    public NavMeshAgent enemy;
    public Transform Player;
    private Rigidbody alienRb;
    private Animator alienAnim;

  

   

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
     
        alienRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        alienAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        enemy.SetDestination(Player.position);

      if(enemy.velocity.magnitude > 0)
        {
            alienAnim.SetTrigger("Walk");
        }

    }
        
       
    

}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Is the player with the animator the child of another gameobject which has a rotation?

Comment: What is the GameObject setup of the alien? If any component for displaying or moving the 3D model has a rotation offset, use that. If the 3D model is a separate object inside a parent GameObject, rotate that child object. In the worst case, try putting the visual elements of the NPC in a child GameObject and rotating that.

Answer (score 0):

Hello **Mazza** ^^ First of all, I have to say that your alien monster is really cute :D Anyway, did you try `transform.LookAt(Player.transform.position)`? Also, transform.rotation is might not be affective, maybe you can try `alien.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f, Space.Self);` or `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y - 180f, transform.rotation.z)`